# How to get git includeIf work for submodule

Tags: git, config, git-submodules

```
[core]
    editor = \"C:\\Microsoft VS Code\\bin\\code\" --wait

[includeIf "gitdir/i:D:/code/project/"]
   path = project.gitconfig

[includeIf "gitdir/i:D:/code/project/acts/ccxt/ccxt"] # not working, why?
    path = github.submodule.gitconfig

[includeIf "gitdir/i:E:/code/project/"]
    path = project.gitconfig

[includeIf "gitdir/i:d:/OneDrive/code/"]
    path = project.gitconfig

[includeIf "gitdir/i:D:/code/github/"]
    path = github.gitconfig
```

`D:/code/project/acts/ccxt/ccxt` is a submodule of `D:/code/project/acts/`.
All `includeIf` work except the one in the submodule. If I comment out `D:/code/project/acts/` and change `D:/code/project/acts/ccxt/ccxt` to `D:/code/project/acts/` it works, but I need different settings for `ccxt` and `project`.

Comment: Where this config with `includeIf`s is? Is it a global config or a local for a superproject? Local config cannot work because every submodule is a separate repository and has its own local config. For a local config you should move corresponding `includeIf`s to the config of the submodule.

Comment: @phd it is in my home (user) directory

Comment: The global config? That should work. Try debugging with `git config --list --show-origin`

Comment: @mugi did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically a git repository will have its config located in `.../repository/.git/config`. In a submodule, that configuration is not actually located in the submodule's `.git` directory, it's located in the parent repository's `.git` directory.

In your case, the parent repository is `D:/code/project/acts/`, so your submodule's config directory is actually located in `D:/code/project/acts/.git/modules/ccxt/ccxt/config`. This means that your `includeIf` should look like this:

```
[includeIf "gitdir/i:D:/code/project/acts/.git/modules/ccxt/ccxt"]
    path = github.submodule.gitconfig
```

Answer (score 0):

i finally got this to work by removing the trailing slash (only for submodules)

gitconfig:

```
[user]
        email = "peter@default.com"
        name = "Peter"
        signingKey = "23DAXXXXXXXX"

[includeIf "gitdir:~/repos/company/"]
        path = "/nix/store/464dis986sd2rgqxhf18wyixm68n0iv2-company-gitconfig"

[includeIf "gitdir:~/.password-store/.git/modules/company"]
        path = "/nix/store/464dis986sd2rgqxhf18wyixm68n0iv2-company-gitconfig"
```